# A future used in Future.sequence fails - which failure is reported and when?

Tags: scala, future

Multiple futures can be combined into one using [Future.sequence](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.5/scala/concurrent/Future$.html). The result is obvious when all of them succeed - it is the sequence of the results, which is available once all of them have completed. What is however not clear, and I did not find it documented, is what happens when some (perhaps even multiple) futures fail. My [Scastie experiment](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ZTUQg80YSgGcvNyF7t5UpA) seems to indicate that as soon as any future fails, the failure is reported immediately.

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.util._

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration

val f1 = Future {
  Thread.sleep(600)
  println("f1 done")
}
val f2 = Future {
  Thread.sleep(400)
  println("f2 done")
  throw new Exception("Failed")
}
val f3 = Future {
  Thread.sleep(200)
  println("f3 done")
  throw new Exception("Failed")
}

val results = Future.sequence(Seq(f1, f2, f3))

results.onComplete {
  case Success(_) =>
    println("Seq completed")
  case Failure(_) =>
    println("Seq failed")
}

Await.result(results, Duration.Inf)
```

Gives result:

> f3 done
>
> Seq failed

Are there any guarantees or specification regarding which failure is reported and when once any of the futures fails?

Comment: It is not documented because it is ... well ... undocumented, meaning that any specific behavior is not guaranteed. If _some_ futures fail, then _some_ failure is returned. In practice, it'll be the first failure that is _detected_ (which is not necessarily the same thing as the first one that _occurred_).

Answer (score 2):

Which future is returned is an implementation detail.

The current implementation of `Future.sequence` in turn depends on the implementation of `zipWith`, which implementations of the `Future` trait are freely allowed to override, so it's not just a dependence on `Future.sequence`'s implementation but also on whatever library is giving you `Future`s (and things like `Future.successful`/`Future.failed` can behave differently from a `Future { }` or even a `Future` derived from something like a `ZIO` or a Cats-Effect `IO` or an Akka ask).

In short, correctness should never depend on which failure is returned from `Future.sequence`: all you can depend on is that at least one of the futures failed.

Comment: This claim does not sound really right to me. Please have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/76372198/6566916

Answer (score -1):

This is not really an answer but I cannot post this as a comment. I believe that the claim that is made on this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73254365/6566916) that

> all you can depend on is that at least one of the futures failed

is wrong and here's a code snippet that debunks it

```scala
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =

    val ec = scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(
      Executors.newWorkStealingPool(4)
    )
    val futures = Seq(
      Future {
        while true do Thread.sleep(1)
      },
      Future {
        Thread.sleep(5000)
        2
      },
      Future {
        throw new IllegalAccessError()

      },
      Future {
        while true do Thread.sleep(1)
      }
    )

    try
      Await.result(Future.sequence(futures)(ec),Duration.Inf)
//      Await.result(Future.firstCompletedOf(futures)(ec), Duration.Inf)
    finally
      println("the end")
```

This code for `sequence` never exits. On the other hand, if you use `firstCompletedOf` is exists in 5 seconds - like it's waiting for the `Thread.sleep` to complete.

I am also confused by this trying to find if the the `Futures` API really returns when any of the futures in a `Seq` completes with a failure.

Comment: I do not think this contradicts the claim. You have a future which never completes (with failure or success) here. In such case even the sequence containing the future never completed. The claim was that if the `Future.sequence` reports failure, then some future failed. You seem to contradict the converse implication claim: if one of the futures failed, the `Future.sequence` fails as well.

Comment: What about the `firstCompletedOf` though? This should wait for nothing and exit immediately in case one of the futures produce an error. Based on the docs `Asynchronously and non-blockingly returns a new Future to the result of the first future in the list that is completed. This means no matter if it is completed as a success or as a failure.`

Comment: What happens when you make `val ec` `implicit`?  Are you sure the tasks in your `Future`s are executing concurrently?

Comment: @LeviRamsey Shouldn't futures be executed in parallel by default?

Comment: @LeviRamsey if I convert the ec to an implicit then the behavior is the same. I would expect for `wait` to return immediately but it seems like it waits 5 seconds (one of the `Thread.sleep`) and then exits.

Comment: Whether futures are executed in parallel depends on the interaction of the future implementation, and the execution context in use

Comment: Downvoted because, while it is a valid concern, it's _not an answer_.  It is a good question on its own.

Comment: @LeviRamsey Are you sure that is useless? You just mentioned yourself that it's a valid concern

Comment: And you yourself, said it's not an answer.  Your snippet also in no way debunks the other answer, and since SO frowns on extended discussions in comments, it's best posted as a question.